# Using Linq to Compare two Lists

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list

Okay I have a list and I want to combine objects with the same first name into one and add the siblings to the others list of siblings.

```
public class People
{ 
    string Name {get; set;}
    List<string> siblings {get; set;}
}
```

Now I have a list that looks like

```
 List<People> list3 = new List<People> 
 {  
     new People
     {
        name = "Chris",
        siblings = {"Richard"}
     },
     new People
     {
        name = "Billy",
        siblings = {"Thomas"}
     },
     new People
     {
        name = "Bob",
        siblings = {"Charles"}
     },
     new People
     {
        name = "Chris",
        siblings = {"Simon"}
     }
 }
```

Now I want it to turn into:

```
 List<People> list3 = new List<People> 
 {  
     new People
     {
        name = "Chris",
        siblings = {"Richard", "Simon"}
     },
     new People
     {
        name = "Billy",
        siblings = {"Thomas"}
     },
     new People
     {
        name = "Bob",
        siblings = {"Charles"}
     }
 }
```

Comment: You're code has errors on the property names and the siblings initialization first of all.

Comment: @RyanEmerle just been trying selectMany with select

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your current way of concatenating list shouldn't work, otherwise you need:

```
var query = list3.GroupBy(r => r.Name)
                .Select(grp => new People
                {
                    Name = grp.Key,
                    Siblings = grp.SelectMany(r => r.Siblings).ToList(),
                });
```

For getting a combined list you can do:

```
List<People> list3 = list1.Concat(list2).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

I think something like this should work.

```
var list3 = list2.Concat(list1).GroupBy(p => p.name)
    .Select(g => new People{
        name= g.Key, 
        siblings = from p in g
                   from s in p.siblings
                   select s
    });
```

Comment: +1, it can also be like this: `siblings = g.SelectMany(p=>p.siblings)`